How to disable function argument fillers in coc-clangd
I am using neovim with coc.nvim installed.
How do I disable the fillers/placeholders in the functions?
Thanks in advance.
Os: Linux Mint
my coc-settings.json:
{
  "jedi.enable": true,
  "jedi.startupMessage": false,
  "jedi.markupKindPreferred": "plaintext",
  "jedi.trace.server": "off",
  "jedi.jediSettings.autoImportModules": [],
  "jedi.executable.command": "jedi-language-server",
  "jedi.executable.args": [],
  "jedi.completion.disableSnippets": false,
  "jedi.completion.resolveEagerly": false,
  "jedi.diagnostics.enable": true,
  "jedi.diagnostics.didOpen": true,
  "jedi.diagnostics.didChange": true,
  "jedi.diagnostics.didSave": true,
  "jedi.workspace.extraPaths": [],
  "jedi.jediSettings.caseInsensitiveCompletion": false,
  "clangd.path": "~/.config/coc/extensions/coc-clangd-data/install/18.1.3/clangd_18.1.3/bin/clangd",
  "clangd.arguments": [
        "--function-arg-placeholders=0"
    ],

  "inlayHint.enable": false
}



I myself was looking for this feature. I took this from your coc-settings.json:
"clangd.arguments": [
  "--function-arg-placeholders=0"
]

And it worked for me!!
Seems like this isn't working for you because of older clangd version. My clangd version is 18.1.8 whereas your clangd version is 18.1.3.
I think you should update your clangd in order to get this work. If still this doesn't help, try to updating coc.nvim as well.
See this for more info.

Thank a lot! I will try this.

Sadly this did not work. I tried updating clangd to 18.1.8, 19 and 16 but nothing worked
And I can see with top that clangd is running with --function-arg-placeholders=0 enabled.
any further help would be appreciated.

Sorry for the late response. Have you tried --function-arg-placeholders=false, false instead of 0? In my case, both worked perfectly.
Also, if you have installed coc-clangd with coc.nvim, you don't need to manually specify the path (with "clangd.path")

Thanks I have tried both 0 and false and clangd accepts them but coc still inserts the placeholders :(

Try installing coc-clangd and don't use "clangd.path" to specify the executable. Let coc-clangd will get the latest and working version for you. And then try using --function-arg-placeholders=0 (or false)

so I'v tried a bunch of things and although it fixes it for functions like: printf statements like if still expand to if(expression). does anyone have a fix for this

May be you want to open up a issue in the GitHub repo?
